# PHP: parsing a specific json value

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to retrieve the first two ("period": 0 and "period": 1) **icon_url** values from the json file showed at the bottom.

However, I'm stuck at:

```
for($j=0; $j<2; $j++) {
$icon[$j] = $parsed_json_forecast->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}->
```

How to parse the first two icon_url values?

Of course it can't be:

```
[...]->{'period'}->{$j}->{'icon_url'};
```

Here's the json content:

```
{
    "response": {
        "version": "0.1",
        "termsofService": "http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
        "features": {
            "forecast": 1
        }
    },
    "forecast": {
        "txt_forecast": {
            "date": "2:00 AM CEST",
            "forecastday": [{
                "period": 0,
                "icon": "rain",
                "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif",
                "title": "Martedì",
                "fcttext": "Pioggia. Massima: 77F. Velocità del vento: 15-25 mph. Direzione del vento: Ovest. Possibilità di precip. 90%.",
                "fcttext_metric": "Pioggia. Massima: 25C. Velocità del vento: 30-40 km/h. Direzione del vento: Ovest. Possibilità di precip. 90%.",
                "pop": "90"
            },
            {
                "period": 1,
                "icon": "partlycloudy",
                "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
                "title": "Martedì notte",
                "fcttext": "Pioggia. Minima: 63F. Velocità del vento: 5-15 mph. Direzione del vento: Ovest-NE.",
                "fcttext_metric": "Pioggia. Minima: 17C. Velocità del vento: 5-20 km/h. Direzione del vento: Ovest-NE.",
                "pop": "0"
            },
            {
                "period": 2,
                "icon": "clear",
                "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
                "title": "Mercoledì",
                "fcttext": "Sereno. Massima: 77F. Velocità del vento: 5-10 mph. Direzione del vento: Sud.",
                "fcttext_metric": "Sereno. Massima: 25C. Velocità del vento: 10-15 km/h. Direzione del vento: Sud.",
                "pop": "0"
            },
            {
                "period": 3,
                "icon": "clear",
                "icon_url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
                "title": "Mercoledì notte",
                "fcttext": "Sereno. Minima: 64F. Vento leggero.",
                "fcttext_metric": "Sereno. Minima: 18C. Vento leggero.",
                "pop": "20"
            },      
[....]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday[$j]->icon_url`. You are indexing into an array, use array syntax. What is confusing about it?

Comment: That "period" value somewhat confused me (I'm still unexperienced with arrays). Of course you're right.

Comment: Thanks to anybody to answered. Sometimes it's difficult to choose just an answer as "the right one", I hope you'll understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the JSON string. Now, to extract the required values, you'll have to do:

- decode the the JSON using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)
- loop through the required items
- store them in your array

Code:

```
$parsed_json = json_decode($str);

for($j=0; $j<2; $j++) {
    $icon[$j] = $parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday[$j]->icon_url;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/rain.gif
    [1] => http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif
)
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/TU0FOQF6)

Answer (score 2):

When you have parsed the JSON data (e.g with `json_decode`) you may access each value using the regular php array syntax:

```
$json["forecast"]["txt_forecast"]["forecastday"][0]["period"].
```

**Edit:** It's the same for array access (SPL):

```
$json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday[0]->icon_url
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AmalMurali How does it not? Parsing json without decoding would be very resource heavy if you are thinking of preg_match or like.

Comment: No. The OP is using objects, but you're using associative arrays in your answer instead.

Comment: Only if you pass `true` as second argument to `json_decode`, objects are parsed into associative arrays.

Comment: @FelixKling The question is not about the type of object, its about how to access the data.

Comment: Yes, but you can only use array syntax to access JSON data encoded as objects if you pass `true` as second argument and you don't mention that. If the OP just uses `json_decode`, they won't be able to use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to parse your json data using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and you can able to extract the data,

Here's the sample code,

```
$data = json_decode($json);
for($j=0; $j<2; $j++) {
    echo $data->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday[$j]->icon_url;
}
```

Code Demo: http://codepad.org/O9WsTs34